# Django-Filer: How to invoke upload widget outside admin

Tags: django, django-filer

How do I invoke the upload widget outside Admin?
Using the standard form below does not work. The widget is corrupted.

```
forms.py
class PhotoAdd(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('ImageFilerField',)


views.py
def photoadd(request):
  context={}
  context['form'] = PhotoAdd()
  render(request, 'template.html', context)


template.html
{{ form }}
```

There is absolutely no reference to this in the documentation. 
How can I upload photos outside admin?

Edit: (added generated code from django above)

```
<label for="id_doc_pic">Doc pic:</label>
</th>
 <td>
   <span class="filerFile">
   <img id="id_doc_pic_thumbnail_img" src="/static/filer/icons/nofile_48x48.png" class="quiet" alt="no file selected" />
   &nbsp;<span id="id_doc_pic_description_txt"></span>
   <a href="/admin/filer/folder/last/?_to_field=file_ptr" class="related-lookup" id="lookup_id_doc_pic" title="Lookup">
   <img src="/static/admin/img/icon_searchbox.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Lookup" /></a><img id="id_doc_pic_clear" class="filerClearer" src="/static/admin/img/icon_deletelink.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="Clear" title="Clear" style="display: none;" /><br />
   <input class="vForeignKeyRawIdAdminField" id="id_doc_pic" name="doc_pic" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript" id="id_doc_pic_javascript">
    django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var plus = django.jQuery("#add_id_doc_pic");
        if (plus.length){
            plus.remove();
        }

        django.jQuery('#id_doc_pic_javascript').remove();
    });
</script>
</span>
```

Javascript Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: django is not defined"

Could it be that I need to know what css to include and what javascript files to load?

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted?

Comment: There is a javascript error. And a new text input field is visible. A click on the magnifier does not open a pop-up, but moves directly to the filer folder window. a selection of a image is not possible because the control to do so is missing. I will post the generated html code.

Comment: I too want to know this, unfortunately the google group seems all but dead and there is no documentation as you mentioned.  It is a great plugin I am sad it seems like it isn't supported anymore.

Comment: @caliph did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately the app isn't designed to be used outside the admin, see https://github.com/divio/django-filer/issues/894

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/43380918/977622

Answer (score 3):

First of all, add `{{ form.media }}` in your html file, just after the tag `<form>` and `{% csrf_token %}`. Then extend the media class in your `ModelForm` of `forms.py` as explained by SteinRobert on Github issue: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6028. It works perfect! Thanks Stein!